# Debugging: Track raw pointer propagation

Tags: c++, debugging

I am debugging a huge legacy code with a `heap-use-after-free` issue. The address sanitizer has let me know where in the code the allocation happened, where it was freed and where the use was afterwards which has been massively useful.

In order to debug, I need to keep track of this faulty memory address i.e. the pointer and how it propagates through the code from allocation to the bad use. It could potentially be copied into some other variables (either free or class member variable) eventually making its way to the bad use. Is there any way in to track the address propagation using debugger?

PS: I know the origin pointer variable that holds the address returned from the allocation (using ASAN).

Comment: Some debuggers allow setting of "data breakpoints" - there are various types of data breakpoints, but one type will cause execution to stop when some expression (e.g. the value of a variable, or data at some address) is read by the program being debugged.   You haven't specified your debugger (or development environment) though - so you'll need to read documentation for your debugger to see if (and, if so, how) it provides such a capability.

Comment: If it is too cumbersome to track the usage through the program via your editor's search functionality, you could try to comment out the original pointer, check the compiler errors to find the usage places, comment out the pointers there too, compile again, etc

Comment: I'm using `gdb`. It does provide `awatch` that I thought of reaching out to, but that would break on read/write to the memory and not the pointer/address propagation. I could put `awatch` on the origin variable but I would need to add more variables to `awatch` as it propagates further. @Peter

Comment: It is the *value* of the pointer that is propagating, so watching the pointer will suffice.   To propagate, its value needs to be accessed.   But, yes, that will require setting additional watch points, for example, each time another variable is assigned the value of the original (and subsequent) pointers.

Comment: @Peter `awatch` and `rwatch` are hardware breakpoints which cause `gdb` to exit once they go out of scope. I am having trouble with those unfortunately since the code path is very long.

Answer (score 1):

Under macOS there are so-called [`lldb.macosx.heap`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-159/examples/darwin/heap_find/heap.py.auto.html) scripts which are available system-wide and provide extra diagnosis means to `lldb`. Let's assume you have a minimalistic code like this (where quite a few pointers refer to a deleted instance of `int`):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void func(int* var) {
    int* newPtr = var;
    std::cout << *newPtr << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int* ptr = new int{2};
    delete ptr;
    int* ptr2 = ptr;
    func(ptr);
}
```

First, under debug session, you need to load these tools:

```
(lldb) command script import lldb.macosx.heap
"malloc_info", "ptr_refs", "cstr_refs", "find_variable", and "objc_refs" commands have been installed, use the "--help" options on these commands for detailed help.
```

Then, provided you have the execution stopped at `std::cout` line, and can see the address `newPtr` points to (in my case it's `0x000060000000c000`), you can print all other pointers which points to the same address:

```
(lldb) ptr_refs 0x000060000000c000
0x00007ff7bfeff1f0: stack in frame #0 of thread #1: tid 0x14e058 in variable at 0x7ff7bfeff1f0:
    (int *) newPtr = 0x000060000000c000
0x00007ff7bfeff1f8: stack in frame #0 of thread #1: tid 0x14e058 in variable at 0x7ff7bfeff1f8:
    (int *) var = 0x000060000000c000
0x00007ff7bfeff210: stack in frame #1 of thread #1: tid 0x14e058
0x00007ff7bfeff218: stack in frame #1 of thread #1: tid 0x14e058 in variable at 0x7ff7bfeff218:
    (int *) ptr2 = 0x000060000000c000
0x00007ff7bfeff220: stack in frame #1 of thread #1: tid 0x14e058 in variable at 0x7ff7bfeff220:
    (int *) ptr = 0x000060000000c000
```

Finally, under `lldb` you can inspect what `frame #1` actually is with use of `frame` command:

```
(lldb) frame select 1
frame #1: 0x0000000100003115 CPPPlayground`main at main.cpp:19:5
   16       int* ptr = new int{2};
   17       delete ptr;
   18       int* ptr2 = ptr;
-> 19       func(ptr);
            ^
   20   }
(lldb) frame info
frame #1: 0x0000000100003115 CPPPlayground`main at main.cpp:19:5
```

Comment: Very nice tool! Can I run it on Linux if I install `lldb`?

Comment: @User10482 frankly I have never bothered myself figuring this out and not sure whether you can just copy-paste some of the scripts and run them under Linux, however [GDB to LLDB command map](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html) says that `ptr_refs` is available on macOS only